# Different width for each columns in jspdf autotable?

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

My table has 13 columns. How can I get different width for each column? Can I give each column width like this?

**styles: {overflow: 'linebreak' ,columnWidth: [100,80,80,70,80,80,70,70,70,70,60,80,100]},**

My table Syntax:

```
> var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById(tableID)); 
> doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {  styles: {overflow: 'linebreak'
> ,columnWidth: [100,80,80,70,80,80,70,70,70,70,60,80,100]},  startY:
> 60,  bodyStyles: {valign: 'top'},  });
```

Comment: Why do you need to specify the width of each column? Does the auto width calculation not work for your use case?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You would have to transform your columnWidth array to look like this:

```js
doc.autoTable({
  html: '#table',
  columnStyles: {
    0: {cellWidth: 100},
    1: {cellWidth: 80},
    2: {cellWidth: 80},
    // etc
  }
});
```

Note the use of `columnStyles` instead of `styles`.

Comment: Hi Simon, this is what I was looking for. Thank you !

Comment: Just noticed an error in your code, it must be 

                          `columnStyles: {
      0: {columnWidth: 60},
      1: {columnWidth: 40},
      2: {columnWidth: 100}
                                  // etc
      }`

Comment: Yes @Becky! It got resolved. Your code also works fine.

Comment: Hi sir,Its Useful for me.I want another Option.How to set column text align right???

Comment: In the new version, columnWidth is deprecated, this necessary change to cellWidth.

Comment: I have a common logic for jspdf export as there are tons of pages where I need export functionality, then do I need to add columnstyles for each page ?? Can I not set the width dynamically ?

Answer (score 10):

In previous release (1.3.4) it could have done like below:

```
var columns = [
          {title: "Signum", dataKey: "signum"},
          {title: "Name", dataKey: "name"},
          {title: "Role", dataKey: "role"},
          {title: "Location", dataKey: "location"} 
          ]
```

But the latest one i.e. 2.3.2 requires the below format

```
doc.autoTable(colums,data,{
    addPageContent:pageContent,
    margin: {horizontal:5,top: 20},
    startY: 0.47*doc.internal.pageSize.height,
    styles: {overflow: 'linebreak'},
    columnStyles: {
     id: {columnWidth: 25}, 
     name:{columnWidth:40}, 
     role: {columnWidth: 15}, 
     location: {columnWidth: 30}
    }
  });
```

This will fix only id, name, role, and location to the specified limits. Rest other headers will be adjusted accordingly by autotable.js

Comment: In the new version, columnWidth is deprecated, this necessary change to cellWidth

Answer (score 4):

Let's say,[ steps,Methods,process,Delivers,Results ] are all my Table Headers.If i want to increase or decrease table width mean's ,

```js
columnStyles: {
    steps: {columnWidth:215},
    Methods: {columnWidth: 60},
    process: {columnWidth: 100},
    Delivers: {columnWidth: 90},
    Result: {columnWidth: 90}
}
```

Here you can specify the each column width.

Comment: In the new version, columnWidth is deprecated, this necessary change to cellWidth

Answer (score 2):

By default the 'columnsStyles' dont have in 'Options',  that's necessary create it and next step you define the 'columnWidth'.

```
Options['columnStyles'] = {
  0: {columnWidth: 50},
  1: {columnWidth: 'auto'},
  2: {columnWidth: 'wrap'},
  3: {columnWidth: 150}
}
JSPDF.autoTable(columns, values, Options)
```

Comment: In the new version, columnWidth is deprecated, this necessary change to cellWidth